# Check python paho MQTT connection created

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I've got device connection with python mqtt:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
client = paho.Client()
client.connect(MQTT_BROKER, 1883, 60)
client.username_pw_set(username=USERNAME_BROKER, password=PASSWORD_BROKER)
client.publish(id, value, 0)
client.disconnect()
```

How can I check, if connection successfully created? For example, add some logs? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and have you read the (pretty good) API docs?

Comment: Thanks, I did, but still hope to find the decision

Comment: The doc contains callbacks that will fire once a connection is established, they are pretty sensibly named `on_connect`...

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but if I use 'single' method I don't initialize client and could not call client.on_connect()

Comment: [`single`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/publish.py#L16C47-L17C34) allows "straightforward publishing of messages in a one-shot manner"; it will only return when the message has been transmitted (for QOS1/2 this includes handling acknowledgments) and will continually retry the connection if initial attempts fail. If you want to do something more complicated then you will need to write this yourself. [`publish.py`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/publish.py) provides a good starting point (copy/modify it).

Comment: @AnnaBerezko no where in the question do you mention `single`, the example you provided clearly shows you instantiating a client... we can only work with the information given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish a single message and then disconnect use [`single`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#single); this will "publish a single message to a broker, then disconnect cleanly".  i.e.:

```
single(topic, payload=None, qos=0, retain=False, hostname="localhost",
    port=1883, client_id="", keepalive=60, will=None, auth=None, tls=None,
    protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport="tcp")
```

The repo includes an [example for `multiple`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/publish_multiple.py) (pretty much the same as `single` but sends more than one message).

If you want to do this yourself then take a look at how [`single` is implemented](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/publish.py#L180) and follow the same pattern (i.e. start a message loop and use the call backs; you can add your own logging in `_on_connect` if you want to see when the connection is up).

The reason the above is important is because the paho library is driven by a [network loop](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#network-loop). Your code *might* work but what it's effectively doing is:

- Establish a TCP connection to the server
- Send a CONNECT packet (not waiting for any response)
- Send the publish packet
- Disconnect

Because you are not waiting for the connection acknowledgment from the server you are really just assuming that the connection was successful (e.g. your username/password is correct). Starting the loop and using callbacks to trigger events (as is done in `single`) enables you to ensure that the connection is successful (and also check that QOS1+ messages are properly acknowledged).

If you just want logs then use [`enable_logger()`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/tree/master#enable_logger); [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/client_logger.py) demonstrates that.

Comment: Thanks, I used your advice and rewrote the functionality. How can I be sure that the message reached the device in this case?: single(
            id,
            value,
            hostname=MQTT_BROKER,
            auth={'username': USERNAME_BROKER, 'password': PASSWORD_BROKER}
        )

Comment: You do not. There is NO end to end delivery notification in the MQTT protocol, the best you can do is use QOS to be sure the message has reached the broker. If you need end to end delivery notification you have to implement it yourself (by sending a response message)

Comment: You are using QOS0 which is "At most once" delivery (i.e. fire and forget; the server does not acknowledge the message). As @hardillb says there is no end-to-end delivery confirmation (the message may go to 0 or many subscribers) but you can use QOS 1/2 to confirm delivery to the server (single will only return when the appropriate acknowledgments have been received from the server).